# Forming nested JSON from POJO's using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am struggling to form the correct JSON object from my POJO's. Apologies, this is a bit long winded, I'm just learning Java -> JSON tooling.  I need the following structure:

```
{
   "firstName":"John",
   "lastName":"Doe",
   "addressLine1":"1 High Street",
   "addressLine2":"",
   "addressLine3":"",
   "addressLine4":"Buffalo",
   "zipCode":"22313",
   "customerEntitlements":[
      {
            "entitlementCode": "6",
            "entitlementType": "G",
            "validFrom": "1980-04-22",
            "validTo": "2026-11-17",
            "customerRestrictions": []
          },
          {
            "entitlementCode": "4",
            "entitlementType": "L",
            "validFrom": "1980-04-22",
            "validTo": "2026-11-17",
            "customerRestrictions": []
          }
   ],
   "customerPresent":null,
   "customerConsentFormSighted":null,
   "customerCheckConsent":true,
   "dob":"1982-01-01",
   "customerEndorsements":[]
}
```

My POJOs as they stand:

`Customers`

```
@Data
public class Customers {


    @JsonProperty("firstName")
    private String firstName;
    @JsonProperty("lastName")
    private String lastName;
    @JsonProperty("addressLine1")
    private String addressLine1;
    @JsonProperty("addressLine2")
    private String addressLine2;
    @JsonProperty("addressLine3")
    private String addressLine3;
    @JsonProperty("addressLine4")
    private String addressLine4;
    @JsonProperty("zipcode")
    private String zipcode;
    @JsonProperty("customerPresent")
    private String customerPresent;
    @JsonProperty("customerConsentFormSighted")
    private String customerConsentFormSighted;
    @JsonProperty("customerCheckConsent")
    private Boolean customerCheckConsent;
    @JsonProperty("dob")
    private String dob;
    @JsonProperty("customerEndorsements")
    private List<Object> customerEndorsements = null;
    @JsonProperty("customerEntitlements")
    private List<CustomerEntitlements> customerEntitlements;

}
```

`CustomerEntitlements`

```
@Data
public class CustomerEntitlements {

    @JsonProperty("entitlementCode")
    private String entitlementCode;
    @JsonProperty("entitlementType")
    private String entitlementType;
    @JsonProperty("validFrom")
    private String validFrom;
    @JsonProperty("validTo")
    private String validTo;
    @JsonProperty("customerRestrictions")
    private List<Object> customerRestrictions = null;
}
```

My code to add the payload ready to send:

```
  c = new Customers();

        ce1 = new CustomerEntitlements();
        ce2 = new CustomerEntitlements();

        ce1.setEntitlementCode("B");
        ce1.setEntitlementType("F");
        ce1.setValidFrom("1980-04-22");
        ce1.setValidTo("2026-11-17");
        ce1.setCustomerrRestrictions(new JSONArray());

        ce2.setEntitlementCode("D");
        ce2.setEntitlementType("F");
        ce2.setValidFrom("1980-04-22");
        ce2.setValidTo("2026-11-17");
        ce2.setCustomerrRestrictions(new JSONArray());

   
        c.setFirstName("John);
        c.setLastName("Doe");
        c.setAddressLine1("1 High Street);
        c.setAddressLine2("");
        c.setAddressLine3("");
        c.setAddressLine4("Buffalo");
        c.setZipcode("22313");
        c.setCustomerEntitlements(Arrays.asList(ce1, ce2);
        c.setCustomerPresent(null);
        c.setCustomerConsentFormSighted(null);
        c.setCustomerCheckConsent(true);
        c.setDob("1982-01-01");
        c.setCustomerEndorsements(new JSONArray());
```

My (malformed) JSON output from the code:

```
{
   "firstName":"John",
   "lastName":"Doe",
   "addressLine1":"1 High Street",
   "addressLine2":"",
   "addressLine3":"",
   "addressLine4":"Buffalo",
   "zipcode":"22313",
   "customerPresent":null,
   "customerConsentFormSighted":null,
   "dob":"1956-01-01",
   "customerEndorsements":[

   ],
   "customerEntitlements":[
  {
        "entitlementCode": "6",
        "entitlementType": "G",
        "validFrom": "1980-04-22",
        "validTo": "2026-11-17",
        "customerRestrictions": []
      },
      {
        "entitlementCode": "4",
        "entitlementType": "L",
        "validFrom": "1980-04-22",
        "validTo": "2026-11-17",
        "customerRestrictions": []
      }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Use the website http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ and paste your json, it generates the pojos for you

Comment: @bigbounty thank you, I'm aware of that site but for some reason cannot unzip the archived POJOs on Macbook ~ error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see only difference is with the `customerEntitlements`. And I believe your setter would be something like,

```
public void customerEntitlements(List<CustomerEntitlements> customerEntitlements)
```

and when you do,

```
c.setCustomerEntitlements(Collections.singletonList(ce1)); 
c.setCustomerEntitlements(Collections.singletonList(ce2));
```

where you can see that the ce2 overrides the ce1, instead you must do,

```
c.setCustomerEntitlements(Arrays.asList(ce1, ce2));
```

Hope it helps..

Note: If ordering is also a concern, I believe you would be aware of your `Pojo->Json` ordering

May be you can try re-order,

```
    @JsonProperty("firstName")
    private String firstName;
    @JsonProperty("lastName")
    private String lastName;
    @JsonProperty("addressLine1")
    private String addressLine1;
    @JsonProperty("addressLine2")
    private String addressLine2;
    @JsonProperty("addressLine3")
    private String addressLine3;
    @JsonProperty("addressLine4")
    private String addressLine4;
    @JsonProperty("zipcode")
    private String zipcode;
    @JsonProperty("customerEntitlements")
    private List<CustomerEntitlements> customerEntitlements;
    @JsonProperty("customerPresent")
    private String customerPresent;
    @JsonProperty("customerConsentFormSighted")
    private String customerConsentFormSighted;
    @JsonProperty("customerCheckConsent")
    private Boolean customerCheckConsent;
    @JsonProperty("dob")
    private String dob;
    @JsonProperty("customerEndorsements")
    private List<Object> customerEndorsements = null;
```

Comment: thank you, that makes sense, yes of course, the setter was being set each time.  I now have valid JSON but still unclear why the final 4 elements are appended before the customerEntitlements object

Comment: @Steerpike, have edited my answer with the re-ordering info, may be that would help you..

Comment: esh Muralidharan perfect! Seems so obvious now.